# C++ Checking Against Particular Numbers

Tags: c++

Hello Dear Programmers, 
I've been working on a piece of code for a while, but I don't seem to figure this out, i'm trying so hard to check an input with a specific number, but so far it ends up not working and even when number 2,3, or 4 is pressed the error message pops up, and I go to my if else condition. here are the codes, number_of_bedrooms is an integer.

```
out << "Number Of Bedrooms: (Limited To 2,3, and 4 Only)" << endl;


    if (isNumber(number_of_bedrooms) == false ) {

        cout << "Please Do Enter Numbers Only" << endl;
        cin.clear();

    } 

    else if (number_of_bedrooms != '2' || number_of_bedrooms != '3' || number_of_bedrooms != '4') {

        cout << "Numbers Are Only Limited To 2,3, And 4" << endl;
        cin.clear();

    }
```

and the function :

```
 bool isNumber(int a)
{

    if (std::cin >> a)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

the first validation which checks for numbers works fine, but the second validation no, my guess is the system is not capturing inputted data after that boolean function. And if that's the reason, what's the solution ?!!

Comment: `return std::cin >> a;`, also you probably want to take that int by reference. Otherwise the change to `a` is local to the function.

Comment: You are comparing the number_of_bedrooms with char types. (number_of_bedrooms != '2'). The '2' is a char.

Comment: so how can I compare it? I mean anyway to convert ?

Comment: @PeterCrouch: Compare it with numbers like `2`, not characters like `'2'`. Streaming it with `>>` already did the conversion from a character sequence to a numeric value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `||` to `&&`, also you need to compare to `int` not `char`

```
else if (number_of_bedrooms != 2 && number_of_bedrooms != 3 && number_of_bedrooms != 4)
```

Note that a more general way to solve such a problem (for example if your list got much longer) would be to do something like

```
std::set<int> const allowableBedrooms = {2,3,4};
else if (allowableBedrooms.find(number_of_bedrooms) == allowableBedrooms.end())
{
    // Warn user here
}
```

Comment: Almost there. `int &a` for the `isNumber()` parameter would be helpful, too.

Comment: I go for the warning even when I do type in 2,3 or 4.

Comment: @PeterCrouch Change your other function from `bool isNumber(int a)` to `bool isNumber(int& a)`

Comment: Yea, it worked man, but can you explain to me what just happened ? I mean that "&" makes it a pointer , right ?

Comment: @PeterCrouch No. It means it takes a *reference* to the passed-in variable, which is subtly different than a pointer (it can't be "re-pointed" to another variable, for example). The main thing: since it's now referring to the original variable (not a copy of its value, as before), changing `a` *in* the function also changes the variable that was passed in.

Comment: @PeterCrouch When you didn't pass the argument by reference `&`, you passed a **copy** of the variable. When you `cin` to the variable, it reads fine, but then falls out of scope. When you do pass by reference, you `cin` to the actual variable `a` that you passed in.

Comment: Thank you very much for consideration and explanation of codes, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

As your goal conditions are sequential, I'd use something like this:

```
else if ( number_of_bedrooms < 2 || number_of_bedrooms > 4 ) {
    cout << "Numbers Are Only Limited To 2,3, And 4" << endl;
    cin.clear();
}
```

This is very clear and easy to manage if you want to change it. If you want to enumerate everything you'll need to use && instead of || since your want it to both be not 2 and not 3 and not 4 to trigger the issue.

Another problem in your code is that you're comparing against characters by putting the numbers in single quotes. Since these are integers you should not have them in quotations.

Comment: I still get the error even when I enter in 2,3 or 4 !

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your function to make the change out of the local function like this:

```
bool isNumber(int * a)
{

    if (std::cin >> * a)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And then call the function with the address of number_of_bedrooms like this:

```
out << "Number Of Bedrooms: (Limited To 2,3, and 4 Only)" << endl;


    if (isNumber(&number_of_bedrooms) == false ) {

        cout << "Please Do Enter Numbers Only" << endl;
        cin.clear();

    } 

    else if (number_of_bedrooms < 2 || number_of_bedrooms > 4) {

        cout << "Numbers Are Only Limited To 2,3, And 4" << endl;
        cin.clear();

    }
```

Check the code above becouse i took off the '' that means you are comparing number_of_bedrooms (int) with '2' (char) so it will be always true.
The condition i wrote would be better then becouse you are considering an interval of numbers, if you are considering the specific numbers you can leave your condition but you should change the logical operator in && and chain with the other != conditions

Comment: I'd rather recommend a refernce parameter: `bool isNumber(int& a)`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ i prefer explicit the pointer parameter and then call the address of the variable instead of define a reference paramater, but your solution will still work

Comment: _"i prefer explicit the pointer parameter "_ Why so? It makes everyting just more error prone.

Comment: becouse if i have  4 parameters and 2 passed byval and 2 passed byref with my way you will distinguish easily which variables are passed byref and which byval improving the understanding of the function and know which one will be affected by the changes.

Comment: `void func(int& a, int& b, int c, int d){
    a=1; b=1; c=1; d=1;
}`


`void func(int * a, int * b, int c, int d){
    *a=1; *b=1; c=1; d=1;
}`

i will prefer the second one of course.